# Obtain intercept using bife in R for fixed effects logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am trying to estimate a logistic regression model with fixed effects using the `bife` package in R. I used this link - [bife vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bife/vignettes/bife_introduction.html) - to set up the model. My model looks like the following when used in `bife` command:

```
logit.bife <- bife(Y ~ X1+X2+X3+X4+...+X13 | ID)
```

When I use bife, how do I get the intercept value? Is it contained in the average fixed effects, which we get in the output? The average fixed effects can be obtained using `logit.bife$par_corr$avg_alpha`. I have about 1266 ID values, and I get 1256 values for fixed effects estimates using `logit.bife$par_corr$avg_alpha`. But, I don't know how to get the intercept value. The vignette indicates that `bife` estimator is almost the same as that of `glm`. Usually when we use `glm` we get an intercept in the model output.

Can anyone suggest how to get the intercept while using `bife`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no single intercept. As it says in `?bife`,

> The term fixed effect is used in econometrician's sense of having a
>   time-constant dummy for each individual. All other parameters in the
>   model are referred to as structural parameters.

and

> The linear predictor must not include any constant regressors due to
>   the perfect collinearity with the fixed effects.

So, essentially we have a separate intercept for each ID, which is the whole point of `bife`. If you defined a constant regressor and manually added it to the model then it would crash due to perfect multicollinearity: one could not distinguish contribution of the intercept and the sum of all the fixed effects.

However, note that in addition to the average fixed effects you also have individual ones, which should be only more interesting than a single figure:

```
logit.bife$par$alpha # Uncorrected
logit.bife$par_corr$alpha # Corrected
```

And indeed, there is nothing special in this sense about `bife`, the same would happen with `glm` if you included a dummy variable for *each* ID (just including the `ID` variable probably would drop one factor level and include the intercept). Ultimately you should think what your goal is; perhaps the average or median of those fixed effects is indeed what you need.

Comment: @Rnovice, does it answer your question?

Comment: thank you for the detailed response. I am not particularly focusing on each individual fixed effect in my model. I am controlling for those effects. I am accepting your answer.

Comment: In `bife` version 0.7.1 it looks like this is directly available as `logit.bife$alpha`